# looping through an array of spans seems to remove all of the metadata

Tags: javascript, html

I have made an array of spans, when I console log it I can see that it contains all of the metadata (maybe metadata is the wrong word here) that I want.

[image]

However, when I loop through the code and console.log each item all of the metadata disappears and it just displays the inner text.

[image]

This is a problem because I am trying to access the parent element, but it's returning null.

I have tried using console.dir instead of console.log but that came back completely blank.

My JavaScript is below, thank you for any input!

```
// Select all <span> elements
    const spanElements = document.querySelectorAll('span');

// Convert the NodeList to an array
const spanArray = Array.from(spanElements);

   // Select all <span> elements containing the estimated job length
    const lengthElements = spanArray.filter(element => element.innerText.includes('Estimated job length:'));
    console.log('lengthElements ', lengthElements)
    // Create an array to store the estimated job lengths
    const lengths = [];

    // Loop through the selected elements and extract the estimated job lengths
    for (let i = 0; i < lengthElements.length; i++) {
        console.log(`lengthElements[${i}] `, lengthElements[i])
        // Get the text inside the <span> element
        const text = lengthElements[i].innerText;
        console.log(`text ${text}`)

        // Extract the hours and minutes from the text
        const [hours, minutes] = [text.split(' ')[3], text.split(' ')[5]]

        // Get the checkbox element with the corresponding id
        const checkbox = document.getElementById(lengthElements[i].parentElement);
        console.log('length checkbox', checkbox)


        // Check if the checkbox is checked
        if (checkbox.checked) {
        // Add the hours and minutes to the array if the checkbox is checked
            lengths.push({ hours: Number(hours), minutes: Number(minutes) });
        };
    }
```

Comment: Please  post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: The console is listing all possible attributes of a DOM node, and pointing out that they are `null` in your case.  The nodes you're working with do not actually contain those attributes (hence the `null`) so nothing is being "lost".

Comment: I'm pretty sure the problem you're having is here: `document.getElementById(lengthElements[i].parentElement)`.  getElementById expects you to pass in an ID, but you're instead passing in a DOM node.

Answer (score 0):

This is an X/Y problem.

Share the HTML and I can fix it easily.

The following is not a valid statement, since you do not pass an ID

`document.getElementById(lengthElements[i].parentElement);`

but fixing that will not help because you cannot have a checkbox parent element to a span or any other element because `input` is a `void element` and does not have a close tag in HTML

You need find the wrap or wrap the input AND the span in a label or other container. Then I would loop over all checked checkboxes in the nearest common static container and see if the `inputElement.nextElementSibling` or `inputElement.closest("label").querySelector("span")` had the text.